# Getting Vine PostID from Video URL

Tags: c#, video, vine

I'm using Vine API wrapper "VineSharp" nuget package to try and get some details about a Vine video. 
I have the video URL. i.e. : "https://vine.co/v/eYgeYlYAOQv"
However, to get the vine post data, apparently VineSharp (as well as other Vine API wrappers) requests to insert the vine post ID - which I don't have.

I've searched google a lot to find out how can I get the post ID if I have the video URL or the video ID - but couldn't find anything.

If Vine API supports posts queries to get details of specific posts using the post's id, it won't be logical that the post ID itself can be retrieved only from Json of another API call like a timeline or channel request...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

A kind of hacky way to do this is downloading the contents of `https://vine.co/v/eYgeYlYAOQv` with the [`WebClient` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and parsing the result with a regular expression.

The post ID appears multiple times in the returned web page. You could use one of the following regular expressions (or both to be sure):

```
vine://post/(\d+)[^\d]
```

```
"postIdStr":\s*"(\d+)"
```

The first match group will contain the post ID.

Here is a working example that tries both patterns: https://regex101.com/r/aV9fD8/4

Here is a working example that downloads the website, tries both patterns and prints the first matching post ID: https://dotnetfiddle.net/klWnxw

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{       
    var content = client.DownloadString("https://vine.co/v/eYgeYlYAOQv");

    var postIdMatch = Regex.Match(
        content, 
        @"vine://post/(\d+)[^\d]|""postIdStr"":\s*""(\d+)""");

    if (postIdMatch.Success)
        Console.WriteLine(
            postIdMatch.Groups[1].Value != string.Empty 
                ? postIdMatch.Groups[1].Value 
                : postIdMatch.Groups[2].Value);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No post ID found.");
}
```

Output:

> 1270971006727159808

Comment: I assumed that can be done, but I thought that if some guys were kind enough to implement Vine API wrapper, they would complete the job...

What is the use of [^\d] in the regular expression though? It works well without it...

Comment: @AvnerHoffmann, yeah that's true. Just forgot that matching will be greedy anyway.